# What is the best replace for header location of php in js?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

What is the equivalent of php header location function

```
<?php 
header("location:somepage.php");
?>
```

in javascript? Does javascript has something that can do the same like the header function? If yes, what's that?

Answer (score 5):

The javascript equivalent is;

```
window.location.href = "somepage.php"
```

More info: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_page_redirect.htm

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the `meta` Tag to immediately redirect the user to another page, no javascript needed:

```
<html>    
  <head>      
    <title>Your Title</title>      
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='http://example.whatever.com/'" /> 
  </head>    
  <body> 
      <!-- NO CONTENT -->
  </body>  
</html>
```

This is a clientside operation not a server redirect.

Comment: This makes the redirect happen all the time. WIth Javascript, it can be controlled by program logic, and it happens after other script code runs.

Comment: That was not the question.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript for redirect:

```
window.location="http://www.example.com";
```

More info: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_page_redirect.htm

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is executed in your browser so it will not be able to do exactly the same as what happens when you request a php that has a redirection. If what you want is just to acces another page, without a request to the server, this is enough:

```
window.location.href = "somepage.php"
```

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, the equivalent to header is:

**index.html (or index.php)**

```
....some html code
<script> 
  window.location="example.php";
</script>
```

Remember that file example.php must be in directory of your local server (if you use XAMPP or WAMPP).